# Has_many through - One Sided Uniqueness in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a three models:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :filters, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :keywords, :through => :filters, :uniq => true
end

class Filter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feed
  belongs_to :keyword

  validates_uniqueness_of :keyword_id, :scope => :feed_id
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :filters, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :feeds, :through => :filters
end
```

What I want is to have only unique entries in the database for keywords. For example, if two feeds both have a keyword 'hello', there should be two filters (one for each feed) both pointing to the same keyword.

What I am having trouble with is the controller code. Perhaps I am looking for too simple a solution, but I figure there must be an easy way to do this. This is what I have in my create action so far:

```
def create
  @feed = Feed.find(params[:feed_id])
  @keyword = @feed.keywords.create(params[:keyword])


  redirect_to feed_keywords_path(@feed), notice: 'Keyword added successfully.' 
end
```

With this controller code, the previous example would result in a duplicate keyword in the database, one for each feed/filter. Is there a straight-forward solution to this or do I need to do a check beforehand to see if there is already a keyword and in that case just create the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dynamic finder `find_or_create_by` :

```
def create
  @feed = Feed.find(params[:feed_id])
  @keyword = Keyword.find_or_create_by_keyword(params[:keyword]) # I assume here that you have a column 'keyword' in your 'keywords' table
  @feed.keywords << @keyword unless @feed.keywords.all.include?(@keyword)

  redirect_to feed_keywords_path(@feed), notice: 'Keyword added successfully.' 
end
```

Comment: The problem with this as far as I can tell is that, although you are not creating any duplicate keywords, you also are not creating the filter object that needs to be created to join the keyword to the feed in the database.

Unless that's what the '<<' is doing. But I would think that is just pushing it onto the end of the array.

Comment: I've never tried, but according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association, it should create the join model. Have you tried ?

Comment: Although I had to make two small changes it did work! Thanks a lot. That is a much more elegant solution than I had figured out. Here is what I had to change:

`@feed.keywords << @keyword unless @feed.keywords.all.include?(@keyword)`


The .all was need to make it an array instead of a Relation (Rails 3) and as far as I can tell contains is not a class method on Arrays, but include? works

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer with your line. `contains` comes from Java ;-)